# Error in running application in android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-xml

I have created a a to z kids application in android it was working fine till now. But some time it shows error like[image]

### EDIT:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

1. Close the emulator
2. clean the project
3. Right click on the project, click Run > "Run Configuration"
4. Click on emulator, check the box which says "Wipe out data before starting"
5. Press Run

Comment: :I have wiped data according to you.But then I am getting another error by the emulator as in my edited question.